# Why is $\Delta u$ bounded, if $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$. Why must $\Delta u$ be bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure of a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact.  A continuous function on a compact set is bounded.

Comment: But doesn't that imply that $u$ itself is bounded, too?

Comment: Yes, $u$ is also bounded.